# ASP MVC + HttpWebRequest application that obtains auth cookie, how do i force it to work?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httpwebrequest

**Final update at the end of this post**

I am working on it whole day, and i cannot make it work:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var loginUri = new Uri(@"http://localhost:5898/Account/Login");
    const string strLoginData = "Login=ojejq&Password=ojejqjejq&returnUrl=%2F";

    var cookie = GetAuthCookie(loginUri, strLoginData);
}

public CookieContainer GetAuthCookie(Uri loginUri, string data)
{
    var cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(loginUri);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    var myWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
    myWriter.Write(data);
    myWriter.Close();
    request.GetResponse();

    return cookieJar;
}
```

In my `ASP MVC` application, I have a `/Account/Login` `POST` controller that is not even hit by above code. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Two login actions in my asp mvc app:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login()
{...}
```

and

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{...}
```

Second update: added login model

```
public class LoginModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Login", ResourceType = typeof(NameResources))]
    [StringLength(16, ErrorMessageResourceName = "LoginLengthError", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(NameResources), MinimumLength = 4)]
    public string Login { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password", ResourceType = typeof(NameResources))]
    [StringLength(32, ErrorMessageResourceName = "PasswordLengthError", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(NameResources), MinimumLength = 8)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Third update: I forgot to mention, that in my web.config i have cookieless="AutoDetect" option set. I don't know if it makes any changes?

**Final update:** First of all, thank you guys for your time, everyone who tried to help me gets an upvote. I found out that the problem was not in the code, but in my visual studio dev server. It somehow redirected my button1 **POST** request, lost data in the process, and changed that request into a **GET** request. I know, werid, but the code was OK. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you add the signature of the controller action? (Account/Login)

Comment: `[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login()` and `[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)`

Comment: Guys code for button1 is a standard c# application that is ment to obtain auth cookie from my other asp mvc app

Comment: @Erwin, my button1 code only hits GET login action, it should hit only POST one...

Comment: @ojek update your question with the code, it's more readable then also add the code of your LoginModel.

Comment: @ojek also add the LoginModel.

Comment: `cookieJar` is the `CookieContainer` for the request, not the response. You'll need to capture the response coming back from `GetReponse` and examine the cookies there.

Comment: @Mike McCaughan, even if i did examine it, it still is not hitting the valid action in asp mvc controller.

Comment: @ojek, you asked, "What am I doing wrong?" Since I didn't have enough information to provide a full answer, I left a comment about one particular thing you're doing wrong, as indicated by @YasserSinjab's answer, where he returns `webResponse.Cookies`.

Comment: Are you getting an exception? You are saying that the HttpPost action is not hit but what happens on the `request.GetResponse()` line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should try "UserName" insted of "Login" in:

```
const string strLoginData = "UserName=ojejq&Password=ojejqjejq&returnUrl=%2F";
```

and try this too:

```
public CookieCollection GetAuthCookie(Uri loginUri, string data)
{
    var cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(loginUri);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    var myWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
    myWriter.Write(data);
    myWriter.Close();

    var webResponse = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    return webResponse.Cookies;
}
```

Comment: Well, this should hit his controller method (assuming his LogInModel has a property named UserName) but it won't make the full code works.

Comment: Actully it works for me,it returned a cookie with "__RequestVerificationToken"

Comment: right, I did comment on the first answer (without GetAuthCookie() snippet). I think now it should work, you got my +1

Comment: @Yasser Sinjab, the only change you have done is `var webResponse = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;` right? Because it STILL is not hitting my [POST] action. :-/

Comment: @ojek , i changed your "strLoginData" variable too.First:check your 'LoginModel' Properties, Then pass them as parameters.

Comment: @Yasser Sinjab, i updated my first post and included my login model. So as you can see my strLoginData should be ok. Also, if i remove `GET` login action from my asp mvc application, my button1 program is crashing saying that there is 404not found... (even if `POST` login action is still there!)

Comment: Ok i'll tell you what i did.I kept "AccountController" as default ,but i commented the "[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]" attribute in HttpPost "Login" method.Then i create WPF App , after that i copy your code,paste it and thats it :)